# Modify my /etc/hosts to work with two apps on different ports?

Tags: localhost, development-environment, host

I am developing a web app that will have two parts running on two separate domains (RoR at mydomain.com and another server at sub.mydomain.com).  When developing locally, I can run the apps on localhost:port1 and localhost:port2.

In order to test, it'd be convenient to modify my /etc/hosts file to work as such:

```
mydomain.com -> localhost:port1
sub.mydomain.com -> localhost:port2
```

Is there a way to do this?  What do people suggest doing to develop both at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosts file is completely unaware of TCP ports.
It is for name to layer 3 resolution only.

The solution posted by mfussenegger is interesting, but I think the easier question to ask is this:
Why is it necessary to run these on separate ports?
Using any web server that supports HTTP 1.0, you can simply define the host header for each site to be the domain name of that site, and the requests will be routed to the appropriate site.

Your hosts file would have both entries just pointing to localhost.

Link to apache documentation on how to configure this:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to run a webserver like nginx or apache. A nginx config might look like this:

```
server {
    listen          8080;
    server_name     mydomain.com

    root            /path/to/your/static/files;

    location    / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8090;
    }
}

server {
    listen          8080;
    server_name     sub.mydomain.com

    root            /path/to/your/static/files;

    location    / {
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8092;
    }
}
```

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8092;` being the url to your RoR app.